# VBA Recordset does not return all data

Tags: excel, vba

I've been editing an excel macro that prints a SQL query (which basically shows every item ordered in a delivery order).

So the problem is I noticed that the recordset misses the last two rows from every query I send.

For example: if I send a query with 24 items only shows 22.

If I try the same query in the DDBB it works perfectly fine.

I changed the printing to the worksheet to a listbox (just to try because I noticed the row range was the one needed) and in the listbox it adds 2 rows BUT it doesn't show the results as I show in the image below.

[image]

The code is the following (I can't show the query but as I said it works fine in the database):

```
Set remoteCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

remoteCon.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver}" _
          & ";SERVER=" & "" _
          & ";DATABASE=" & "" _
          & ";UID=" & "" _
          & ";PWD=" & "" _
          & ";PORT = "

remoteCon.Execute ("USE db;")

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Sql = 'here goes the query

Set rs = remoteCon.Execute(Sql)
     
If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    myArray = rs.GetRows

    filas = UBound(myArray, 2) 'filas
    
    UserForm1.ListBox3.ColumnCount = 2
    UserForm1.ListBox3.ColumnWidths = "50,50"
    
    For j = 0 To filas
        UserForm1.ListBox3.AddItem
        UserForm1.ListBox3.List(j, 0) = myArray(0, j)
        UserForm1.ListBox3.List(j, 1) = myArray(1, j)
    Next j

End If
```

Comment: Actually I see nothing wrong here. Is there a `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in your code? To me it looks like the issue is in the code part you **didn't** show.

Answer (score 1):

Loop is not necessary. You can use list.column.

```
If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    myArray = rs.GetRows

    filas = UBound(myArray, 2) 'filas
    
    UserForm1.ListBox3.ColumnCount = 2
    UserForm1.ListBox3.ColumnWidths = "50,50"
    UserForm1.ListBox3.Column = myArray
'    For j = 0 To filas
'        UserForm1.ListBox3.AddItem
'        UserForm1.ListBox3.List(j, 0) = myArray(0, j)
'        UserForm1.ListBox3.List(j, 1) = myArray(1, j)
'    Next j

End If
```

Comment: This does not put any data into the list box, or did I miss something? `UBound(myArray, 2)` returns the amount of elements and then you set this number to `UserForm1.ListBox3.Column`? Either I don't get it, or you missed something. ^^

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, When the data  is transposed, use listbox.column, and if the data is in a normal , use listbox.list.

Comment: @JohnnieL, I made a mistake. The answer was corrected.

Comment: @Dy.Lee That looks more logic now but you won't need `filas = UBound(myArray, 2) 'filas` then if you throw out the loop.

Comment: @Dy.Lee what youve written is more concise - but either original code or your proposed answer work for me - turtle cactus can you make this clearer; `"I changed the printing to the worksheet to a listbox (just to try because I noticed the row range was the one needed) and in the listbox it adds 2 rows BUT it doesn't show the results as I show in the image below."` The blank screen shot doesnt add anything IMHO - can you add something more illuminating? thanks

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I cant see `filas` used in the original post so it may be used elsewhere in the module but it is superfluous in the original post code agreed

Comment: @JohnnieL it was used in the loop `For j = 0 To filas`. No where else. Nevermind it is not relevant for the question itself.

Comment: sorry my bad @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Hi! I finally fixed it. Apparently I was missing the last two rows by overwriting some of the values. I now use another variable ```For j = 0 To filas
         UserForm1.ListBox3.AddItem 'myArray(0, i)
        UserForm1.ListBox3.List(global_count + j, 0) = myArray(0, j)
        UserForm1.ListBox3.List(global_count + j, 1) = myArray(1, j)
    Next j
    global_count = global_count + filas + 1```